# home router not working after upgrade

Tags: networking, 18.04, router

I have an apu2 originally running 16.04. I just upgraded to 18.04 and it isn't routing. The logs show that hostapd is working and clients are getting their ips from dhcpd. Pinging the outside world from the router works however clients can't ping the router or the outside world. My iptables haven't changed and are pretty minimal. Has anything changed between the two versions I should look at? Sorry for lack of info but with the router down I'm stuck using my phone.

Thanks

Comment: This sounds like something was configured on the old os that did not remain after the update. So, it is unlikely that we can help without more info. You have already said that you can ping the outside world from the router. How did you connect to it? More information on your setup is better. With too little information the answers are at best a shot in the dark.

Comment: I can access the terminal via null modem. All networking related config files remain and are working. As stated with verifying the logs. Are there new sysctl's or something similar that has changed between 16.04 and 18.04?